# Stripe Proration - Pay Upfront?

Tags: stripe-payments

**Problem:**

I had my first user upgrade to a higher priced subscription plan, under the proration settings, the user is set to be charged a higher amount next month ($84.95 instead of $67).

**Question:**

How can I charge the user the difference ($17.95) upfront, so they are charged this amount when they press upgrade, and then on the next billing cycle get charged just the normal amount ($67)

Is there an option to enable this in Stripe?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrading-downgrading#immediate-payment

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60225670

Answer (score 3):

As ceejayoz mentioned, the solution here is to [generate a one off invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/create-invoice) right after the upgrade.

Generating a one-off invoice pulls in any pending invoice items that would have been added to the regularly scheduled invoice.

Comment: There's no need to explicitly generate an invoice after the upgrade. Stripe can upgrade and charge the user in one API call. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60225670

Comment: Awesome - this is what I'm looking for. Thank you @Flux